# I have an SVG with a linear gradient applied to the fill and it isn't applying the second stop color and I can't figure out why

Tags: css, svg, gradient

I have an SVG with a linear gradient defined that I am applying the colors to using CSS. In practice though, it's only displaying the first color. In the CSS, I can see that the second stop-color is getting the orange rule, but it's not showing up in the SVG and I can't figure out why.

In the code below, the image shows up as solid blue.

```css
linearGradient:nth-child(2n+1) stop:first-child {
  stop-color: blue;
}

linearGradient:nth-child(2n+1) stop:nth-child(2) {
  stop-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 265 255" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="_Linear1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(-1.68,-154.08,154.08,-1.68,61.68,180)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-opacity:1"/>
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-opacity:1"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M2918.29,629.251L2934.79,629.251L2934.79,631.958C2934.79,635.75 2937.87,638.837 2941.67,638.837C2945.36,638.837 2948.47,635.685 2948.47,631.958L2948.47,629.251L2990.32,629.251L2990.32,631.958C2990.32,635.75 2993.41,638.837 2997.2,638.837C3000.95,638.837 3004,635.75 3004,631.958L3004,629.251L3045.92,629.251L3045.92,631.958C3045.92,635.75 3048.97,638.837 3052.73,638.837C3056.52,638.837 3059.6,635.75 3059.6,631.958L3059.6,629.251L3101.45,629.251L3101.45,631.958C3101.45,635.75 3104.54,638.837 3108.33,638.837C3112.08,638.837 3115.14,635.75 3115.14,631.958L3115.14,629.251L3131.63,629.251C3134.25,629.251 3136.37,631.377 3136.37,633.983L3136.37,654.855L2913.55,654.855L2913.55,633.983C2913.55,631.377 2915.67,629.251 2918.29,629.251ZM2940.3,620.944C2940.3,620.248 2940.93,619.659 2941.67,619.659C2942.35,619.659 2942.96,620.262 2942.96,620.944L2942.96,631.958C2942.95,633.43 2940.3,633.358 2940.3,631.958L2940.3,620.944ZM2995.83,620.944C2995.83,620.248 2996.46,619.659 2997.2,619.659C2997.92,619.659 2998.49,620.226 2998.49,620.944L2998.49,631.958C2998.49,633.48 2995.83,633.395 2995.83,631.958L2995.83,620.944ZM3051.43,620.944C3051.43,620.226 3052,619.659 3052.73,619.659C3053.47,619.659 3054.09,620.248 3054.09,620.944L3054.09,631.958C3054.09,633.395 3051.43,633.48 3051.43,631.958L3051.43,620.944ZM3106.96,620.944C3106.96,620.248 3107.59,619.659 3108.33,619.659C3109.05,619.659 3109.62,620.226 3109.62,620.944L3109.62,631.958C3109.62,633.48 3106.96,633.395 3106.96,631.958L3106.96,620.944ZM2908.03,633.983L2908.03,804.918C2908.03,810.569 2912.64,815.171 2918.29,815.171L3079.48,815.171C3081,815.171 3082.24,813.937 3082.24,812.414C3082.24,810.892 3081,809.657 3079.48,809.657L2918.29,809.657C2915.67,809.657 2913.55,807.532 2913.55,804.918L2913.55,660.37L3136.37,660.37L3136.37,756.432C3136.37,757.954 3137.61,759.188 3139.13,759.188C3140.65,759.188 3141.89,757.954 3141.89,756.432L3141.89,657.684C3141.89,657.659 3141.9,657.638 3141.9,657.613C3141.9,657.587 3141.89,657.567 3141.89,657.542L3141.89,633.983C3141.89,628.333 3137.29,623.737 3131.63,623.737L3115.14,623.737L3115.14,620.944C3115.14,617.196 3112.08,614.145 3108.33,614.145C3104.54,614.145 3101.45,617.196 3101.45,620.944L3101.45,623.737L3059.6,623.737L3059.6,620.944C3059.6,617.196 3056.52,614.145 3052.73,614.145C3048.97,614.145 3045.92,617.196 3045.92,620.944L3045.92,623.737L3004,623.737L3004,620.944C3004,617.196 3000.95,614.145 2997.2,614.145C2993.41,614.145 2990.32,617.196 2990.32,620.944L2990.32,623.737L2948.47,623.737L2948.47,620.944C2948.47,617.196 2945.42,614.145 2941.67,614.145C2937.87,614.145 2934.79,617.196 2934.79,620.944L2934.79,623.737L2918.29,623.737C2912.64,623.737 2908.03,628.333 2908.03,633.983Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3109.62,747.995L3056.86,747.995L3056.86,720.237L3109.62,720.237L3109.62,747.995ZM3051.35,781.267L2998.58,781.267L2998.58,753.509L3051.35,753.509L3051.35,781.267ZM2940.3,753.509L2993.07,753.509L2993.07,781.267L2940.3,781.267L2940.3,753.509ZM2940.3,720.237L2993.07,720.237L2993.07,747.995L2940.3,747.995L2940.3,720.237ZM2998.58,686.965L3051.35,686.965L3051.35,714.723L2998.58,714.723L2998.58,686.965ZM2998.58,747.995L2998.58,720.237L3051.35,720.237L3051.35,747.995L2998.58,747.995ZM3109.62,714.723L3056.86,714.723L3056.86,686.965L3109.62,686.965L3109.62,714.723ZM3115.14,750.752L3115.14,684.208C3115.14,682.686 3113.9,681.45 3112.38,681.45L2995.82,681.45C2994.3,681.45 2993.07,682.686 2993.07,684.208L2993.07,714.723L2937.54,714.723C2936.02,714.723 2934.79,715.958 2934.79,717.48L2934.79,784.024C2934.79,785.546 2936.02,786.782 2937.54,786.782L3054.11,786.782C3055.63,786.782 3056.86,785.546 3056.86,784.024L3056.86,753.509L3112.38,753.509C3113.9,753.509 3115.14,752.274 3115.14,750.752Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3085.29,798.679C3085.53,798.75 3085.78,798.779 3086.02,798.779C3087.23,798.779 3088.34,797.982 3088.68,796.755L3089.51,793.753C3091.82,785.389 3095.38,778.654 3100.08,773.75C3101.13,772.644 3101.1,770.899 3100,769.851C3098.89,768.789 3097.14,768.839 3096.1,769.93C3090.76,775.509 3086.75,783.026 3084.2,792.274L3083.36,795.29C3082.95,796.755 3083.82,798.277 3085.29,798.679Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3159.47,796.755C3159.81,797.982 3160.92,798.779 3162.13,798.779C3162.37,798.779 3162.62,798.75 3162.86,798.679C3164.33,798.277 3165.19,796.755 3164.79,795.29L3163.95,792.289C3161.4,783.026 3157.39,775.509 3152.05,769.93C3150.99,768.839 3149.25,768.789 3148.15,769.851C3147.05,770.899 3147.01,772.644 3148.07,773.75C3152.77,778.654 3156.33,785.389 3158.64,793.768L3159.47,796.755Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3107.96,856.809L3141.33,856.809C3139.18,860.384 3133.01,863.493 3124.65,863.493C3116.28,863.493 3110.11,860.384 3107.96,856.809ZM3082.21,848.53C3082.3,847.855 3084.23,846.024 3085.5,844.818C3088.94,841.558 3093.63,837.106 3095.76,829.783C3098.23,821.224 3101.71,808.717 3104.68,797.954C3109.7,779.853 3119.25,779.989 3124.91,779.875C3129.95,779.91 3139.6,779.853 3144.61,797.954C3147.58,808.717 3151.06,821.217 3153.53,829.783C3155.66,837.106 3160.36,841.558 3163.79,844.818C3165.07,846.031 3167,847.862 3167.09,848.487C3167.09,848.487 3166.95,848.946 3166.06,849.65C3163.53,850.611 3148.55,851.154 3132.01,851.294L3115.28,851.294C3099.62,851.17 3085.84,850.686 3083.56,849.844C3082.39,848.989 3082.22,848.53 3082.21,848.53ZM3147.31,856.452C3158.82,856.057 3167.58,855.332 3169.01,854.281C3171.3,852.594 3172.47,850.82 3172.59,848.853C3172.78,845.744 3170.37,843.461 3167.59,840.812C3164.45,837.839 3160.54,834.134 3158.83,828.246C3156.36,819.709 3152.9,807.223 3149.92,796.489C3144.66,777.496 3134.12,774.771 3127.41,774.413L3127.41,766.563C3127.41,765.041 3126.17,763.806 3124.65,763.806C3123.13,763.806 3121.89,765.041 3121.89,766.563L3121.89,774.38C3115.39,774.642 3104.73,777.113 3099.37,796.489C3096.4,807.223 3092.93,819.702 3090.46,828.246C3088.76,834.134 3084.85,837.839 3081.71,840.818C3078.92,843.461 3076.51,845.744 3076.7,848.853C3076.82,850.813 3077.99,852.594 3080.28,854.281C3081.71,855.332 3090.47,856.057 3101.98,856.452C3103.71,863.65 3113,869.007 3124.65,869.007C3136.29,869.007 3145.58,863.65 3147.31,856.452Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like? Your gradientTransform in combination with the units is why it doesn't really work as the gradient isn't really "over" the shapes.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. In a perfect world, it would be neat if it transformed over the entire SVG from one color to the next. I would also be okay with it transforming over each individual path.

Comment: Oh, so I just need to remove the gradientUnits and gradientTransform properties and it gives me the results I wanted! Awesome! Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

```
linearGradient stop:first-child {
  stop-color: blue;
 }

 linearGradient stop:last-child {
   stop-color: orange;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is still leaving me with a solid blue SVG. When I inspect the image, the second stop is getting orange applied to the stop-color property. Thanks for taking a look though!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the gradientUnit and gradientTransform properties gave me the result I wanted!

```css
linearGradient:nth-child(2n+1) stop:first-child {
  stop-color: blue;
}

linearGradient:nth-child(2n+1) stop:nth-child(2) {
  stop-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 265 255" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="_Linear1" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0"  >
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-opacity:1"/>
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-opacity:1"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M2918.29,629.251L2934.79,629.251L2934.79,631.958C2934.79,635.75 2937.87,638.837 2941.67,638.837C2945.36,638.837 2948.47,635.685 2948.47,631.958L2948.47,629.251L2990.32,629.251L2990.32,631.958C2990.32,635.75 2993.41,638.837 2997.2,638.837C3000.95,638.837 3004,635.75 3004,631.958L3004,629.251L3045.92,629.251L3045.92,631.958C3045.92,635.75 3048.97,638.837 3052.73,638.837C3056.52,638.837 3059.6,635.75 3059.6,631.958L3059.6,629.251L3101.45,629.251L3101.45,631.958C3101.45,635.75 3104.54,638.837 3108.33,638.837C3112.08,638.837 3115.14,635.75 3115.14,631.958L3115.14,629.251L3131.63,629.251C3134.25,629.251 3136.37,631.377 3136.37,633.983L3136.37,654.855L2913.55,654.855L2913.55,633.983C2913.55,631.377 2915.67,629.251 2918.29,629.251ZM2940.3,620.944C2940.3,620.248 2940.93,619.659 2941.67,619.659C2942.35,619.659 2942.96,620.262 2942.96,620.944L2942.96,631.958C2942.95,633.43 2940.3,633.358 2940.3,631.958L2940.3,620.944ZM2995.83,620.944C2995.83,620.248 2996.46,619.659 2997.2,619.659C2997.92,619.659 2998.49,620.226 2998.49,620.944L2998.49,631.958C2998.49,633.48 2995.83,633.395 2995.83,631.958L2995.83,620.944ZM3051.43,620.944C3051.43,620.226 3052,619.659 3052.73,619.659C3053.47,619.659 3054.09,620.248 3054.09,620.944L3054.09,631.958C3054.09,633.395 3051.43,633.48 3051.43,631.958L3051.43,620.944ZM3106.96,620.944C3106.96,620.248 3107.59,619.659 3108.33,619.659C3109.05,619.659 3109.62,620.226 3109.62,620.944L3109.62,631.958C3109.62,633.48 3106.96,633.395 3106.96,631.958L3106.96,620.944ZM2908.03,633.983L2908.03,804.918C2908.03,810.569 2912.64,815.171 2918.29,815.171L3079.48,815.171C3081,815.171 3082.24,813.937 3082.24,812.414C3082.24,810.892 3081,809.657 3079.48,809.657L2918.29,809.657C2915.67,809.657 2913.55,807.532 2913.55,804.918L2913.55,660.37L3136.37,660.37L3136.37,756.432C3136.37,757.954 3137.61,759.188 3139.13,759.188C3140.65,759.188 3141.89,757.954 3141.89,756.432L3141.89,657.684C3141.89,657.659 3141.9,657.638 3141.9,657.613C3141.9,657.587 3141.89,657.567 3141.89,657.542L3141.89,633.983C3141.89,628.333 3137.29,623.737 3131.63,623.737L3115.14,623.737L3115.14,620.944C3115.14,617.196 3112.08,614.145 3108.33,614.145C3104.54,614.145 3101.45,617.196 3101.45,620.944L3101.45,623.737L3059.6,623.737L3059.6,620.944C3059.6,617.196 3056.52,614.145 3052.73,614.145C3048.97,614.145 3045.92,617.196 3045.92,620.944L3045.92,623.737L3004,623.737L3004,620.944C3004,617.196 3000.95,614.145 2997.2,614.145C2993.41,614.145 2990.32,617.196 2990.32,620.944L2990.32,623.737L2948.47,623.737L2948.47,620.944C2948.47,617.196 2945.42,614.145 2941.67,614.145C2937.87,614.145 2934.79,617.196 2934.79,620.944L2934.79,623.737L2918.29,623.737C2912.64,623.737 2908.03,628.333 2908.03,633.983Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3109.62,747.995L3056.86,747.995L3056.86,720.237L3109.62,720.237L3109.62,747.995ZM3051.35,781.267L2998.58,781.267L2998.58,753.509L3051.35,753.509L3051.35,781.267ZM2940.3,753.509L2993.07,753.509L2993.07,781.267L2940.3,781.267L2940.3,753.509ZM2940.3,720.237L2993.07,720.237L2993.07,747.995L2940.3,747.995L2940.3,720.237ZM2998.58,686.965L3051.35,686.965L3051.35,714.723L2998.58,714.723L2998.58,686.965ZM2998.58,747.995L2998.58,720.237L3051.35,720.237L3051.35,747.995L2998.58,747.995ZM3109.62,714.723L3056.86,714.723L3056.86,686.965L3109.62,686.965L3109.62,714.723ZM3115.14,750.752L3115.14,684.208C3115.14,682.686 3113.9,681.45 3112.38,681.45L2995.82,681.45C2994.3,681.45 2993.07,682.686 2993.07,684.208L2993.07,714.723L2937.54,714.723C2936.02,714.723 2934.79,715.958 2934.79,717.48L2934.79,784.024C2934.79,785.546 2936.02,786.782 2937.54,786.782L3054.11,786.782C3055.63,786.782 3056.86,785.546 3056.86,784.024L3056.86,753.509L3112.38,753.509C3113.9,753.509 3115.14,752.274 3115.14,750.752Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3085.29,798.679C3085.53,798.75 3085.78,798.779 3086.02,798.779C3087.23,798.779 3088.34,797.982 3088.68,796.755L3089.51,793.753C3091.82,785.389 3095.38,778.654 3100.08,773.75C3101.13,772.644 3101.1,770.899 3100,769.851C3098.89,768.789 3097.14,768.839 3096.1,769.93C3090.76,775.509 3086.75,783.026 3084.2,792.274L3083.36,795.29C3082.95,796.755 3083.82,798.277 3085.29,798.679Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3159.47,796.755C3159.81,797.982 3160.92,798.779 3162.13,798.779C3162.37,798.779 3162.62,798.75 3162.86,798.679C3164.33,798.277 3165.19,796.755 3164.79,795.29L3163.95,792.289C3161.4,783.026 3157.39,775.509 3152.05,769.93C3150.99,768.839 3149.25,768.789 3148.15,769.851C3147.05,770.899 3147.01,772.644 3148.07,773.75C3152.77,778.654 3156.33,785.389 3158.64,793.768L3159.47,796.755Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2908.03,-614.145)">
    <path d="M3107.96,856.809L3141.33,856.809C3139.18,860.384 3133.01,863.493 3124.65,863.493C3116.28,863.493 3110.11,860.384 3107.96,856.809ZM3082.21,848.53C3082.3,847.855 3084.23,846.024 3085.5,844.818C3088.94,841.558 3093.63,837.106 3095.76,829.783C3098.23,821.224 3101.71,808.717 3104.68,797.954C3109.7,779.853 3119.25,779.989 3124.91,779.875C3129.95,779.91 3139.6,779.853 3144.61,797.954C3147.58,808.717 3151.06,821.217 3153.53,829.783C3155.66,837.106 3160.36,841.558 3163.79,844.818C3165.07,846.031 3167,847.862 3167.09,848.487C3167.09,848.487 3166.95,848.946 3166.06,849.65C3163.53,850.611 3148.55,851.154 3132.01,851.294L3115.28,851.294C3099.62,851.17 3085.84,850.686 3083.56,849.844C3082.39,848.989 3082.22,848.53 3082.21,848.53ZM3147.31,856.452C3158.82,856.057 3167.58,855.332 3169.01,854.281C3171.3,852.594 3172.47,850.82 3172.59,848.853C3172.78,845.744 3170.37,843.461 3167.59,840.812C3164.45,837.839 3160.54,834.134 3158.83,828.246C3156.36,819.709 3152.9,807.223 3149.92,796.489C3144.66,777.496 3134.12,774.771 3127.41,774.413L3127.41,766.563C3127.41,765.041 3126.17,763.806 3124.65,763.806C3123.13,763.806 3121.89,765.041 3121.89,766.563L3121.89,774.38C3115.39,774.642 3104.73,777.113 3099.37,796.489C3096.4,807.223 3092.93,819.702 3090.46,828.246C3088.76,834.134 3084.85,837.839 3081.71,840.818C3078.92,843.461 3076.51,845.744 3076.7,848.853C3076.82,850.813 3077.99,852.594 3080.28,854.281C3081.71,855.332 3090.47,856.057 3101.98,856.452C3103.71,863.65 3113,869.007 3124.65,869.007C3136.29,869.007 3145.58,863.65 3147.31,856.452Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please add your own answer as a comment. See [answer] and [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thanks! I added my own answer because Robert Longson pointed me in the correct direction, but it was in a comment to my original post, so I couldn't flag it as "The Answer" I wanted to make sure there was something I could flag as The Answer. Is that not correct?

I also added the correct, working code.

Comment: You should be able to accept it if you wish. Click on the checkmark near the answer till it turns solid green. I would have written an answer once I knew what you wanted but by the time I saw your response you'd already created your own answer, which is perfectly fine IMHO now you've edited it to be complete.